# Shortcode in my childtheme is not working

Tags: shortcode

```
function get_employee_func(&$totalCount)
{
    global $wpdb,$_POST;
    $query='';
    $sql='';
    $query="Select * from wp_users as U left join wp_company_user as CU on U.ID = CU.user_id LEFT JOIN  wp_company as C on CU.company_id = C.company_id  where CU.owner = 'N'";


    $employee = $wpdb->get_results($query);

    $totalCount=count($employee);

    $countRows=1;


     $result = $DB->RunSelectQueryWithPagination($query,$totalCount);

    if ($busCount >10)
    { 
         return $obj;   
    }
    else
    {

        return $employee;
    }    

}

add_shortcode("get_employee", "get_employee_func");
```

I am calling my plugin using via this shortcode

```
[get_employee]
```

I just made a WP- plugin and shortcode for all levels of staff
I want to call it in my child theme as [get_employee] but when i write it in my child theme file it shows like a string as [get_employee]. It should show the result in table format but it don't

Please suggest me if any one has some answer

Comment: How and when do you register the shortcode? Please show us your code.

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. @toscho jumped me here a bit. I see you used the wordpress.com tag which toscho has corrected. The wordpress.com tag is only for blogs hosted at wordpress.com, not for self hosted blogs. BTW, wordpress.com questions is off topic as well here, as wordpress.com have their own support forum

Comment: Sorry for my tag selection but my problem is about to plugin development and shortcodes.
Please help me if you have any solutions

Comment: Welcome to the Stack, @HungerofPHP, but there is no useful way to offer solutions until you post all of the relevant code. Where is the `get_employee_func` function?

Comment: @s_ha_dum  I have modified my question please go through it

Comment: @toscho dear i just modified my full question, M sure you will get full description over here.
please let me know if any further description you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading your question, I think you are calling `[get_employee]` directly from a PHP template file in your child theme. This is not the way shortcodes work. You have three options:

1. Put `[get_employee]` in the content of a post
2. Run `do_shortcode("[get_employee]")` wherever you want in a template file
3. Call directly the function callback wherever you want in your template file

Detail info in the [Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API).

Also note that your are using the class `$DB` and its method `RunSelectQueryWithPagination()` but there is not initialization before you use it. Also, there no definition for `$busCount` and `$obj`, so in the case your shortcode runs correctly I think you won't get the desire output.

Comment: +1. That was my understanding of the question too. I would probably suggest that the OP use [`WP_User_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query) instead, but that is another question altogether.

Comment: @cybnet 
Sir Please tell is it nessesary that we define our function of shortcode into the functions.php file 
can't we make a shortcode of functions which are in another files >>>

Comment: `add_shortcode()` can be called in functions.php file of a theme or in a plugin. I don't know if I understand you corretly when you say "can't we make a shortcode of functions which are in another files", but if in functions.php file, or in a plugin file, you [`include`](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.include.php) the files where the functions are, the is no problem at all.